# how to make carousel slider image responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter

I tried lot but didn't find the solution how to make image responsive and my caption also not in responsive.

here is my html code:

```
<section id="banner">

    <div class="banner-bg">
        <div class="banner-bg-item"><div class="textoverlay"><h3 id="caption1">Suburban Mumbai’s Best Serviced Apartment</h3><h3 id="caption2">The Perfect Home Away From Home</h3>
          </div>
          <img class='img-responsive' src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-1.jpg'); ?>"  alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="banner-bg-item"><div class="textoverlay"><h3 id="caption1">Suburban Mumbai’s Best Serviced Apartment</h3><h3 id="caption2">The Perfect Home Away From Home</h3>
          </div>
          <img class='img-responsive' src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-2.jpg'); ?>"  alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="banner-bg-item"><div class="textoverlay"><h3 id="caption1">Suburban Mumbai’s Best Serviced Apartment</h3><h3 id="caption2">The Perfect Home Away From Home</h3>
          </div>
          <img class='img-responsive' src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-3.jpg'); ?>"  alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="banner-bg-item"><div class="textoverlay"><h3 id="caption1">Suburban Mumbai’s Best Serviced Apartment</h3><h3 id="caption2">The Perfect Home Away From Home</h3>
          </div>
          <img class='img-responsive' src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-4.jpg'); ?>"  alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="banner-bg-item"><div class="textoverlay"><h3 id="caption1">Suburban Mumbai’s Best Serviced Apartment</h3><h3 id="caption2">The Perfect Home Away From Home</h3>
          </div>
          <img class='img-responsive' src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-5.jpg'); ?>"  alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css code:

```
#banner .banner-bg .banner-bg-item {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 650px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#banner .banner-bg .banner-bg-item .img-responsive{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    display:block;

}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #banner .banner-bg .banner-bg-item {
    min-height: 920px;
  }

.banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay{
          padding-top: 30%;
          padding-left: 12%;
          color:  white;
      }
        .banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay #caption1{
          background-color: rgba(0, 26, 9, 0.3);
          width: 640px;
      }
        .banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay #caption2{
          background-color: rgba(0, 26, 9, 0.3);
          width: 500px;

      }
```

I provide the html and css code of my website . i tried it lot but cant able to make my image responsive. for the slider i used owl.crousle ..please help me to find out any way to slove this problem.I searched on google but i didn't find any article ..please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Adding [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) will be quite helpful

Comment: I dont know how to create it

Comment: Please help me to find the solution...

Comment: I don't think anything to do with codeigniter

Comment: Can you add screenshot of the  View

Comment: @wolfgang1983 `base_url('assets/img/slider-4.jpg'); ?>` So its better to ping Codeigniter tag too

Comment: abdullah can you please create chat session then i'll explain you in details

Comment: wolf gang ..i didn't understand what are saying

Comment: Try this. hope it will work
        
        http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Fully-Responsive-Mobile-friendly-jQuery-Carousel-Plugin-Owl-Carousel-2.html 
        
        or
        
        https://www.lennu.net/responsive-jquery-slider-example-with-owl-carousel/

Comment: Remove the padding `padding-top: 30%;
          padding-left: 12%;`  padding should never be in **%** and use the **%** `width` in the `.banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay #caption1{` as well as `.banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay #caption2{` That should make it responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay{
      padding-top: 30%;
      padding-left: 12%;
      color:  white;
  }
    .banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay #caption1{
      background-color: rgba(0, 26, 9, 0.3);
      width: 100%;
  }
    .banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay #caption2{
      background-color: rgba(0, 26, 9, 0.3);
      width: 100%;

  }
```

Use this slider [startbootstrap-full-slider](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-full-slider)

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS,

```
#banner .banner-bg .banner-bg-item {
   height: 75%;
   min-height: 250px;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   width: 50%;
}
.textoverlay {
   height: 10%;
}

#banner .banner-bg .banner-bg-item .img-responsive{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 90%;

 }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
     #banner .banner-bg .banner-bg-item {
      min-height: 920px;
  }

.banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay{
      padding-top: 30%;
      padding-left: 12%;
      color:  white;
  }
    .banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay #caption1{
      background-color: rgba(0, 26, 9, 0.3);
      width: 640px;
  }
    .banner-bg .banner-bg-item .textoverlay #caption2{
      background-color: rgba(0, 26, 9, 0.3);
      width: 500px;

  }
```

For making Responsive Images, its good to specify the height and width in '**%**',
or use **@media** to specify the size for particular screen.
size in '**%**' can change the size of images, but you have to use **@media** and specify the font size for **text**.